# Google Analytics: Track mobile and desktop versions separately when using the same url?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile-website, tracking

I'm currently using the same URL to display both mobile and desktop versions of a site (e.g. www.adomainname.com will detect the device that is being used and show either the mobile version or desktop version of the site on the same url).

How can i set up a Google Analytics profile to detect if the user is looking at the mobile version from the desktop version when they are using the same url?

Is there another way of doing this without setting up a custom variable? (i.e. http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCustomVar)

Comment: I'm using the following code on the mobile site: `gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Version', 'Mobile', 3]);`. Would the following filter setup work: `Filter Type: Custom Filter | Include | Filter Field: User Defined | Filter Pattern: Version=Mobile | Case Sensitive: No`

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an excellent place to use custom variables. Assuming you use a cookie to track when the user has switched from the mobile to the desktop version, you can switch the value of the custom variable at the same time.

This will allow you easily to generate a report on the number of mobile user who use the desktop version (and vice versa), which will be a valuable insight for optimisation.

---

Any reason though that you wouldn't use a different subdomain for tacking purposes? You wouldn't actually need to create a new website - you could just rewrite the URL.

Comment: How do you create a filter to target that specifically?

Comment: Unfortunatley the site has been setup so that it works on the same url, so have to work with that setup. How do you create a filter to target a specific user defined variable? See above notes for what i have set up...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up a profile with some custom include filters that use the "Visitor Operating System Platform" field to select visits that come from the various mobile platforms like "iPhone" and "Android".

Comment: A mobile device user has the options of viewing both the mobile and desktop version of the site. By tracking the device I'm not getting a true picture of which version they are actually looking at.